# Create a APK using Javascript UI

Tags: javascript, apk

If you have a javascript UI and would like to create an APK for Android devices. Please advice how could i compile to get APK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Cordova: [cordova.apache.org](http://cordova.apache.org)

Just follow the steps for installation, turn your JavaScript project into a Cordova project with `cordova run Android` and then build the APK with `cordova build android`.